# Is there an DolphinDB function for finding the index of an element in a vector?

Tags: python, search, dolphindb

In python, I can use `index` to find the index of an element, such as:

```py
# vowels list
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']

# index of 'e'
index = vowels.index('e')
print('The index of e:', index)

# index of the first 'i'
index = vowels.index('i')
print('The index of i:', index)
```

Is there an equivalent function in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

Use function `find` to get the index of an element in a vector. If the element doesn't exist, return -1.

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']
index = vowels.find('e')
```